# Why are the data files not showing up in my executable?

Tags: python, csv, executable, pyinstaller

I have used the necessary commands --add-data to add a series of csv files needed for my game to run. ( I have also modified the spec file to make sure that these files have been included. They are.)

datas=[('*.csv', 'data')]

Looking in the executable file directory--as I have used the --onedir command to generate my executable, my data files have been moved there and are in the specified ("data") folder.  However, when running my executable--these files are not read in.  Any help would be appreciated as my final project is due in 2 days (EEK!) and I have been lost on this problem for a week now.  [The chapter csv files are the only files that are supposed to be read in, but they are not being read in. I am not sure why. I have added them in .spec using datas=](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzeLa.png) I am also using a mac and my partner with windows has not encountered this issue.

Comment: Add an [mcve] and also check [ask] to include all the necessary info if you really want us to be able to help.

Comment: How did you expand the glob construct `*.csv`?  Did you expect it to be done automatically?  Python is not a shell, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html